# How do I use the trigram tokenizer/similarity option with Peewee and SQLite's FTS5?

Tags: sqlite, peewee, fts5

This question concerns how to use FTS5's trigram tokenizer with Peewee.

1. The  [official FTS5 documentation for SQLite cites support for trigram tokenization/similarity](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html):

   ```
    > The experimental trigram tokenizer extends FTS5 to 
    > support substring matching in general, instead of the 
    > usual token matching. When using the trigram tokenizer
    > , a query or phrase token may match any sequence of 
    > characters within a row, not just a complete token.
    > 
    > CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tri USING fts5(a, tokenize="trigram");
    > INSERT INTO tri VALUES('abcdefghij KLMNOPQRST uvwxyz');
   ```
2. I've tried setting up an FTS based class with Peewee. I changed the options to use the trigram tokenizer:

   ```
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fts_test_db'
        database = test_db
        options = {'tokenize': 'trigram', 'content': PrecedentPW}
   ```
3. When I attempt to create a table with those options, this error flips up:

   ```
    _db.create_tables([_fts], )

    >> peewee.OperationalError: no such tokenizer: trigram
   ```
4. But if I change the tokenizer options to use something else (e.g. 'porter'), no errors are raised.

**How can I use the trigram tokenizer with Peewee?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to compile the tokenizer yourself or ensure you are running a new enough version. The trigram tokenizer was not included by default until 3.34.0 of Sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_34_0.html

Comment: I see, thank you. Just to check, is Peewee currently running on SQLite version 3.22, or a different version?

Comment: It works with any SQLite version. You're probably just seeing the version of your system SQLite.